# Is SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList option not available in clang-format installed via Homebrew in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, clang-format

I run `clang-format` with `SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList` option but seems like `clang-format` not know that option. Below is the error message.

```
YAML:98:29: error: unknown key 'SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList'
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
                            ^~~~
Error reading /Path/to/.clang-format: Invalid argument
```

is it happened in `clang-format` installed via `homebrew`? am I missing something?

below is my `.clang-format` file

```
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: All
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth: 1
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:   
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp11
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList` is a fairly new option and was only introduced in a recent commit (June 14th 2018), so it is not yet available in an official release of clang-format:

https://reviews.llvm.org/D46024

There are no nightly LLVM builds for OsX, AFAIK, so if you must have that option, you'll need to build trunk LLVM/Clang from source.